# Keep focus on keyboard when checkbox is selected

Tags: java, swing, button, checkbox, focus

I have a multiple-choice JavaSwing app that has checkboxes and next/previous buttons. I had it modified so focus is now on the Next button when it launches, allowing user to press Enter/Return to go to next screen.

The problem now is when user selects a checkbox, the Next button loses its **keyboard focus** and grey outline. Coder has added a hack so the button is regains focus and grey outline each time a checkbox is selected, but then the button blinks on each mouse-click! Some screens have 4 correct checkboxes, so button blinks 4 times.

I think this is unacceptable behaviour but he says,"Expected behavior is when you select any control its obvious it gains focus on that Element. You are saying to override Java Inbuilt Functionality which is not possible."

This just feels wrong. Is he right? Is there any source I can point him to that will allow him to keep focus on checkboxes on mouse-click, while keeping **keyboard focus** on buttons?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you ask your *own question*? Code examples and in this case, screenshots would be *very* useful.

Comment: Hi -- I didn't think screenshot would help as it's just a screen with checkboxes and navigation buttons. I now cannot see a way to upload an image. Not sure what you mean by asking my own questions. Please elaborate.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I haven't tried anything. It's the coder telling me something cannot be done, when I think it can just because the fix he's added feels wrong. So all i was asking is if what he says is true (IWC, end of story), or he doesn't know it's possible. IWC, if you know of a source or tutorial that keeps keyboard focus on a button but allows user to select checkboxes on same screen, please point to it. I haven't asked anyone to write code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not mess around with the keyboard focus - that only infuriates the users that try to navigate your UI with key strokes only.

What you are looking for is the "default button" that is available on `JFrame`s and `JDialog`s rootpane:

```
public JFrame makeFrame() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame(...);
    JButton next = new JButton("next");
    f.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(next);
    return f;
}

public JDialog makeFrame() {
    JDialog d = new JDialog(...);
    JButton next = new JButton("next");
    d.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(next);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Coder changed buttons to default buttons. Now focus is on buttons so user can press Enter/Return to navigate, and also can select checkboxes. Thanks everyone for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your programmer probably should just set setFocusable(false) on the checkboxes.